# what is the proper mode to load basic jquery document:ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tremendous amount of ways to declare jquery document ready status says that the best one is contextual. Is there any generic mode to abide by?

`document:ready` and `window:load` events are wrapped by jquery various formats, but abbreviations and shortenings are available. ECMA6-7 standards don't point strictly to the uniform format, that's why a question may be posed what is the so called normal practice?

The exact question is *not quarreling* that they are equivalent, but what **works the most normal in terms of benchmarks** and code maintenance?

```
$(function() {
    console.log('document ready');
});

$('dom:ready', function() {
    console.log('dom:ready');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document:ready');
});
```

console output is as expected:

```
document ready
dom:ready
document:ready
```

are there any shortcomings of using abbreviated form `$(function() {})`?

Comment: `$(function() { /* your code here.. */ });` https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: `$('dom:ready', function() { .... })` is not valid. It currently works, but that does not mean that it will work in future as it actually just works due to how argument checking and handling is done, but that it works should be considered as a bug. It is actually equivalent to `$(function() {console.log('dom:ready')}).find('dom:ready')` and the `.find('dom:ready')` is meaningless. So who ever suggested that method has no clue what he is doing. And `$(document).ready(function() {` is deprecated. So out of you three only `$(function() {})` is the one to use.

Comment: The docs are of [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)  pretty clear about that: `[...]As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior.[...]` and that "first syntax" and only recommend way for jQuery is `$(function() {})`.